# Validating three inputs that they should not be same

Tags: html, validation

I am using Boostrap to validate my registration form and I want user to provide three user name which should not be same. Now I cant prevent submitting but the boostrap form still showing that input field is correct, how can I mark it to be invalid for user to know which part they wrong?

html

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <h6 class="d-inline-block pt-3">Please enter 3 choices for login username:</h6>
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label for="sys_user_first" class="form-label">
      First Choice 
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star-of-life required-field fa-xs"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sys_user_first" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please fill in the first choice and three choices should not be same.
    </div>
    <label for="sys_user_second" class="form-label">
      Second Choice 
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star-of-life required-field fa-xs"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sys_user_second" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please fill in the second choice and three choices should not be same.
    </div>
    <label for="sys_user_third" class="form-label">
      Third Choice 
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star-of-life required-field fa-xs"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sys_user_third" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please fill in the third choice and three choices should not be same.
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {


                      if (form.checkValidity() === false||$("#d_sys_user_first").val() === $("#sys_user_second").val() || $("#sys_user_first").val() === $("#sys_user_third").val() || $("#sys_user_second").val() === $("#sys_user_third").val()) {
                          event.preventDefault();
                          event.stopPropagation();
                      }


                      form.classList.add('was-validated');
                  }, false);
```

Comment: You can't add anything to bootstrap, you need to add some JS code for this.

Comment: One way to do is you can setup a submit listener for the form and when the user submits the form check whatever validation you want.

Comment: But how to add js code to set that field to be false

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by false. If you mean adding a different bootstrap class, then you can use classList to do that. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp